# Maschke's theorem and the problem of the irreducible representation

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Need to prove the following statement

Let $\rho_k:<a>_n\rightarrow GL_2(R)$ is representation.
$\rho_k(a)= \left( \begin{array}{cc} \cos {\frac{2 \pi k}{n}} & -\sin{\frac{2 \pi k}{n}} \\ 
 \sin{\frac{2 \pi k}{n}} & \cos {\frac{2 \pi k}{n}} \end{array} \right), 0<k<n.$

To prove that the representation
 $ \rho_k $ is irreducible.

I have the impression that the statement that I should prove contrary Maschke's theorem . After specifying the group is finite. Where am I wrong? And, in general , how to prove irreducibility ? I understand that I have to show: "if the subspace is invariant under $\rho_k $, then it is trivial". But how?
sorry for my poor English

Comment: Could you please explain the notation? What is $a$?What does the subscript $n$ on $\langle a\rangle_n$ signify?

Comment: I assume that $\langle a \rangle_n$ is a group of order $n$ with generator $a$. Then what you really define is $\rho(a^k)$, not $\rho_k(a)$ which is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not invariant subspaces for $n>2$, since $\rho (a)$ is a rotation.